# How to change volume of MediaPlayer in service?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I have an Activity (let call it A) and service (let call it B) with music player in it.

In A there's a seekbar, and I want to change MediaPlayer's volume with it.
Any ideas?

In MainActivity:

```
MusicService mms;
mms = new MusicService();

Settings_Sound_Music_Volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       
    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {               
        sdm.setSetting("SETTINGS_MUSIC_VOLUME",String.valueOf(Settings_Sound_Music_Volume.getProgress()));
        mms.player.setVolume(Settings_Sound_Music_Volume.getProgress(), Settings_Sound_Music_Volume.getProgress());
    }       
    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }       
    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        Settings_Sound_Music_VolumeValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "%");
    }
});
```

But this code crashes my app. I get a NullPointerException at this line: `mms.player.setVolume(...);`

Comment: Any error in the log?

Comment: Which line? Is the player variable null? It would be helpful if you paste the log.

Comment: at this line:mms.player.setVolume(...); Sorry, cant post logs now

Comment: @user2718135 can u pls tell me how u have controlled your volume in service?